# Using macros to name functions in C

Tags: c, macros

The other day I was trying to use a macro to define a function like so (simplified, obviously):

```
#define DEF_ADD(name) \
    int add_name(int x, int y) { \
        return x + y; \
    } \
```

Now, I expected the snippet `DEF_ADD(hello)` to define the function `add_hello`. However, the macro call instead defines a function called `add_name`. I expect that this has something to do with scanning, but I couldn't find a way to recreate the behavior I'm looking for. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: As a side note, inventing macros like this is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Lundin, I'm aware of that, but I tried this out and couldn't find out why it didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need

```
#define DEF_ADD(name) \
    int add_##name(int x, int y) { \
    return x + y; \
}
```

Note well the `##`. I've also dropped the final newline character. Else the parameter `name` is not used and you create `add_name` as the function name.